# Are tiny brown spots on a tooth a sign of tooth decay? If so, is there a way to stop it from spreading or is it too late? Is it a dead tooth?

Tags: coloration-discoloration, tooth-decay, brushing-teeth, floss-flossing

In December, I opened a pantry, and a canned-food item from 2 shelves higher, rolled and fell off the shelf, smacking me in face. It was extremely painful, but I was so relieved that I was not bruised or bleeding on my face and at the time, my teeth seemed fine. But over the course of days and weeks, I noticed that the tooth that took the brunt of can's fall, started to develop slight brown lines that I couldn't brush away. And over the weeks, those slight brown lines, are then those became tiny brown spots... And now, one of those spots are growing, despite double efforts to brush and floss diligently there.

I know you can't diagnose me (and I need to see a dentist for confirmation), but can someone just tell me:

1. ***Is brown spotted discoloration suddenly appearing on a tooth, after
   an injury, a sign of tooth decay? If so, how do you stop it from
   spreading? Or is it not possible?***
2. ***What are the symptoms of a dead tooth? Are they the brown spots? Will these spots continue to spread? Or how does a dentist address this issue?***

Comment: The brown spots **could** be from [dental trauma](http://www.colgate.com/en/us/oc/oral-health/life-stages/adult-oral-care/article/brown-spots-on-teeth-causes-0116) caused by the canned food